# toggling between visiblity hidden and visible doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

The code only seems to hide it when I click on the element but when I click the element again, it does not reappear.

HTML (AngularJS)

```
<div ng-click="showIt();">Click Me!</div>

<div style="visible:{{tog}};">Hide Me...Then Show Me Again</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.showIt=function(){
    if($scope.tog="visible"){
      $scope.tog="hidden";
    }
    else{
      $scope.tog="visible";
    }
}

$scope.tog="visible";
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: The style's name is actually [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility), so it should be `<div style="visibility:{{tog}};">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style is called `visibility` also in the `if` condition you need to use `==` not `=`.

But a better solution will be to use the `ng-style` directive or use a class based solution

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.showIt = function() {
    if ($scope.tog.visibility == "visible") {
      $scope.tog.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
      $scope.tog.visibility = "visible";
    }
  }
  $scope.showIt2 = function() {
    $scope.hidden = !$scope.hidden;
  }

  $scope.tog = {
    visibility: "visible"
  };
  $scope.hidden = false;
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <div ng-click="showIt()">Click Me!</div>
    <div ng-style="tog">Hide Me...Then Show Me Again</div>
    <hr />
    <div ng-click="showIt2()">Click Me!</div>
    <div ng-class="{hidden: hidden}">Hide Me...Then Show Me Again</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "==" was the answer...I will look into ng-style for future...Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

What about `ng-show` directive?

```
<div ng-click="tog = !tog">Click Me!</div>
<div ng-show="tog">Hide Me...Then Show Me Again</div>
```

Comment: That toggles the display property not visibility

Comment: Not the same as what the user is having,... but may be that is what the user is actually after

Comment: Yeah this is great but I want to hide the "click me" div when clicked and only show the "Hide Me...Then Show Me Again" div. It seems all I needed to do was change "=" to "==". Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/V0YOWfqEpQKviooKGR7V?p=preview)

You cal also do it with `ng-if` directive:

```
<div ng-click="showIt();">Click Me!</div>    
<div ng-if="tog">Hide Me...Then Show Me Again</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.tog = true;
    $scope.showIt=function(){
    $scope.tog=!$scope.tog
   }

});
```